# How to set user flood limit role wise?

Tags: 8, users

If user account is locked after entering wrong password 5 times. That's a default setting.

That can be changed via

```
drush cset user.flood user_limit 10
```

I have different roles. I need to set flood user_limit role wise

```
Role A, It will be 10
Role B, It will be 7
```

Can we achieve same thing via CLI?

Comment: There are two modules `https://www.drupal.org/project/flood_settings` and `https://www.drupal.org/project/floodcontrol_settings_api` you can modify them or extend them.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't.

The `user.flood user_limit` config setting feeds into the [`DatabaseBackend::isAllowed()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Flood%21DatabaseBackend.php/function/DatabaseBackend%3A%3AisAllowed/9.0.x) method as the `$threshold` arg, which is used to compare the row count for this query:

```
  $number = $this->connection
      ->select(static::TABLE_NAME, 'f')
      ->condition('event', $name)
      ->condition('identifier', $identifier)
      ->condition('timestamp', REQUEST_TIME - $window, '>')
      ->countQuery()
      ->execute()
      ->fetchField();
```

It only compares the threshold login count against a unique user ID, `$identifier`.

You'd have to do some sort of modification to the `flood` core service to make some sort of per-role flood limit.

Comment: Since the question is asking how to achieve it from the command line interface, this is the only possible answer. Replacing a Drupal service would be one of the alternatives, but writing an answer about that would make the answer too long, considering the question isn't even showing any knowledge of what that means.